# Issues with certian characters causing syntax errors in strings

Tags: java

Proberly a very simple question, but within Java, I have a string as follows:

```
public static String wincpuload = "cmd /c @for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%";
```

Although I get a syntax error because of some of the charcters in the string are breaking it. Similarly in C#, if you have this kind of problem you do:

```
string test = @"C:\testing\test"
```

How can you overecome this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a back slash (\) to escape your double quotes. Note the syntax highlighting below:

**Incorrect**

```
String s1 = "cmd /c @for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%";
```

**Correct**

```
String s2 = "cmd /c @for /f \"skip=1\" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%";
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you use `\` to escape special characters in string.

Answer (score 0):

There are no heredoc in Java, you need to escape the double quotes like this:

```
String wincpuload = "cmd /c @for /f \"skip=1\" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p%";
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating a string where you want characters like " \ you have to place another\ before those characters.